# Use jQuery getScript to load a script that loads another script

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery function:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$.getScript("http://my.cdn.ext/adsense.js");
});
</script>
```

Inside adsense.js, there is:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
google_ad_slot = "xxxxxxxx";
google_ad_width = 250;
google_ad_height = 250;
//-->
</script>
<script src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>
```

The script gives me the following error on firebug;

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement 
<script src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js
```

Since it’s a js file, I tried deleting the  tags and I get no response. What’s the way around this?

Comment: That's an extract from an html file rather than a proper JavaScript file.

Comment: Got rid of the script tags and it did not work. How do you recommend I save the file?

Comment: Remove the script tags, turn the script include into a jQuery getscript maybe?

Comment: Thanks, the getscript suggestion worked but am stuck with the following warning: A call to document.write() from an asynchronously-loaded external script was ignored. This is what I did:$(document).ready(function(){
  $.getScript("http://my.cdn.ext/adsense.js");
  $.getScript("http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js");
});

Comment: original error you posted pertained to `document.write` which can't happen after page load or it will wipe out existing content. Why can't you include as script tags in original html?

Comment: The script will be part of an if else jquery function that will load different scripts based on different conditions